# Create login with execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project and I have access to SQL Server as external user with limited privileges.

When I want to create a login for example with this command, I get permission denied:

```
CREATE LOGIN [login] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF)
```

However when I try to create a login with this command I can make it and also I have privileges now to enable `xp_cmd` shell as well:

```
EXECUTE('EXECUTE(''CREATE LOGIN [test5] WITH PASSWORD=N''''test'''', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF'') AT "hostname\domain"')
EXECUTE('EXECUTE(''ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [test5]'')
EXECUTE('EXECUTE(''ALTER SERVER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [test5]'')
```

Can someone please explain why is that?

Answer (score 0):

EXECUTE('string sql statement') AT "hostname\domain" == the 'string sql statement' is a pass-through command executed at the linked server "hostname/domain".

Has someone created a loop-back linked server (a linked server that points to the sql instance itself)? 
Linked servers have their own security configuration/settings. If the security of the linked server is configured (for any login) to be made under the security context of a privileged login(eg. sa)  then exec('') at linkedserver will be executed with way more/elevated permissions (than expected). This is a major security issue/hole.

Check the security of the linked server and change accordingly (and do you really need a loopback linked server?)

Comment: So sorry but can you explain something to me! why there are two EXECUTE('EXECUTE?? because The EXECUTE statement can be used to send pass-through commands to linked servers